# Best way to pass values between web forms ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms, session

What's the best way for passing values between web forms in ASP.NET. I have several web forms linked to a site master and I want that when certain button is pressed in one form , certain information will be passed to another form and the user will be redirected to that form displaying the information retrieved from the previous form. 
Ex: Form1 --> click --> go to Form2 --> Display in Form2 the data received from Form1.

For testing it I tried using Session variables but it hasn't worked until now. I declare the variable in the Page_Load of Form1 as following:

```
Session["diseno"] = "nombre";
```

but when I go to Form2 I do the following on the Page_Load:

```
Response.Write( (string) Session["diseno"] )
```

however nothing is printed. I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: I was able to see to nombre printed on the second form. does your Response.Write has semi-colon?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the best way for your scenario as its easy to break and not good for secure data you don't want the user to see but I have used URL parameters, They are simple and you can pass multiple parameters.

[**Source**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this on your second page and set the variable to a string etc... and use the variable in a label control etc...

```
string _name = Session["diseno"].ToString();
```

To just print out your session variable do this:

```
Response.Write(Session["diseno"].ToString());
```